# VirtualBox not working on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04

I can't run VirtualBox on Ubuntu Linux 11.04. I've installed the following packages:

```
ii  virtualbox-guest-additions   4.0.4-1                guest additions iso image for VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-ose               4.0.4-dfsg-1ubuntu4.1  x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-ose-dkms          4.0.4-dfsg-1ubuntu4.1  x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
ii  virtualbox-ose-fuse          4.0.4-dfsg-1ubuntu4.1  x86 virtualization solution - virtual filesystem
ii  virtualbox-ose-guest-utils   4.0.4-dfsg-1ubuntu4.1  x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest utilities
ii  virtualbox-ose-guest-x11     4.0.4-dfsg-1ubuntu4.1  x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities
ii  virtualbox-ose-qt            4.0.4-dfsg-1ubuntu4.1  x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

When I run VirtualBox as my user stivlo the QT interface starts, I press New, then Next, I write "test" in the Name field, "Linux" in the Operative System field and select "Linux 2.6" for the version and press Next.

In memory I leave the default 256Mb and press Next. In Virtual Hard Disk, I leave "Boot Hard Disk" checked and also "Create a new Hard Disk" selected and hit Next.

Then Next again in the splash screen for the Create new Hard Disk wizard. As Hard Disk Storage I leave  "Dynamically expanding storage" selected and hit next.

In location I write test-hd and leave the size as 8GB and hit Next and press Finish and Finish again.

I get the following message:

> Failed to create a new virtual machine test. Runtime error opening
>   '/home/stivlo/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml-tmp' for reading: -38 (Access
>   denied.).
>   /build/buildd/virtualbox-ose-4.0.4-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[3302]
>   (nsresult VirtualBox::saveSettings()).

Details:

```
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
VirtualBox
Interface: 
IVirtualBox {d2de270c-1d4b-4c9e-843f-bbb9b47269ff}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you must have run virtualbox as root at some point.

Can you post the response to

```
ls -la /home/stivlo/.VirtualBox
```

If the owner is root, then you can just do

```
sudo chown stivlo /home/stivlo/.VirtualBox -R
```